# Why does Python 3 re.findall fail to find all matches here?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3's [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all occurrences of a substring within a string:

```
import re
full_string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_pattern = 'CDC'
re.findall(sub_pattern, full_string)
```

`re.findall` only finds `['CDC']`, however, the pattern `CDC` occurs 2 times in the full string.

Why isn't `re.findall` finding all occurrences of `CDC` here? 
What's needed so that [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) correctly finds all occurrences?

Comment: Don't forget to take a look at David C answer that is also interesting in the first linked question.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4 which doesn't have the new `regex` module to use that answer.

Comment: It isn't related to the python version, you have to install the module: [the link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (use `sudo pip3 install regex` under linux)

Comment: The example comes from https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-a-string. I ended up solving it without `regex`; it's probably(?) not an allowed library.